# Querying mongoDB on Date using R

Tags: r, mongodb

How can I query data where DOB is lesser/greater than given date? If I have to query for date less than 16-06-1991, How can i do it through R script.

This code gives data where date of birth is equal to 16-06-1991.

```
library(rmongodb)

host <- "localhost:27017"
db <- "myDB"
mongo <- mongo.create(host=host,db=db)
if (mongo.is.connected(mongo)) {
  buf <- mongo.bson.buffer.create()
  mongo.bson.buffer.append(buf, "DOB", ISOdatetime(1991,16,06,05, 31, 00))
  query <- mongo.bson.from.buffer(buf)
  res <- mongo.find(mongo," myDB.Student ",query=query)
}
```

Comment: I tried following R code it's not giving me the correct answer.     library(rmongodb)
host <- "localhost:27017"
db <- "myDB"
mongo <- mongo.create(host=host,db=db)
if (mongo.is.connected(mongo)){
    res <- mongo.find(mongo,"myDB.Student",query=list("{DOB:{$gt:new Date(1991-06-14)}}"))
    out <- NULL
    while (mongo.cursor.next(res)){
      out <- c(out, list(mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(res))))
  }
print(out)                                                          Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the answer :

`library(rmongodb)
    host <- "localhost:27017"
    db <- "myDB"
    mongo <- mongo.create(host=host,db=db)
    if(mongo.is.connected(mongo)){
        queryList <- list(name="Priyanka",
                        DOB=list("$gt"=ISOdatetime(1991,06,14,00,00,00)))
        result <- mongo.find(mongo,"myDB.Student",query=queryList)
        out <- NULL
        while (mongo.cursor.next(res)){
            out <- c(out, list(mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(result))))
        }
        out
    }`

Thanks.